# The SoundCloud SC.Connect mobile friendly pop-up - iOS bug

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am trying to use the SoundCloud SC.Connect mobile friendly pop-up as Shown in the Javascript SDK examples.

It works on all desktop browsers, however on Safari iOS 5.0 iPod Touch, latest model, it doesn't. It gets to the 'this popup should close in a few seconds' message and no further.

Other iOS devices have not been tested.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reporting this!

Seems like some new restrictions in mobile safari on iOS5 are preventing the
closing of the popup window automatically.

So far the only workaround I found was adding a link in the callback.html 
Close
that the user has to click to finish the authorization.

I'll try to come up with a more elegant solution and let you know about it, but this is at least a quick fix for now.

Comment: Ahh i see, no worries.
Could i have an example of the link for now please?
Thanks